# Is it possible to have JSP servlevt without URL mapping?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a simple dashboard displaying some record. Now I want to add edit function. Because the items are HTML elements I cannot query the server with POST data, because the user simply clicks an link with parameters in URL.

```
dash.html+--GET-->dashServlet
                   ^     +
                   |     |
                   |   forward
                   |     |
                   |     v
                   +--editServlet
```

On the diagram above is what I want. The page will send `GET` request `dashServlet` this servlet will forward the request to dedicated `editServlet`. This servlet would return control to `dashServlet` which would render the updated page.

I got this working. The problem is, the `editServlet` now mapped in `web.xml`. Is there any way to hide the `editServlet` from public? So to sum this up, how to make private server?

This is an course assignment. So we cannot use Spring, Struts or other frameworks.

Comment: Place the mapping into the /WEB-INF path... the container won't forward requested to that path from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Can you make this a proper answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do, is to place the Servlet mapping into the /WEB-INF path... the container does not forward requests to that path (/WEB-INF) from outside the container.